# failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\w+=,.@-]+

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-iot, aws-policies

I am trying to apply a policy for an identity pool in AWS. I am using awc-cli to set up the policy but it constantly gives me this exception from the title:

> An error occurred (InvalidRequestException) when calling the AttachPrincipalPolicy operation: 1 validation error detected: Value ''DeviceShadowPolicy'' at 'policyName' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\w+=,.@-]+

This is the command I use:

```
aws iot attach-principal-policy --policy-name 'DeviceShadowPolicy' --principal 'PRINCIPAL'
```

I do not understand why do I get this error. Could somebody help me out?

Comment: I'd check a couple of things: 1) make sure you have the latest version of awscli and 2) try this operation using the AWS Console, supplying the same policy name (does it work?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently, the answer was that it has to be without the single quotation sign. All the examples I saw had it with a quotation sign but for me it worked without.

Hopefully, that helps somebody.

Answer (score 2):

I have this issues when I m using `aws cli` inside the `bash script`

The error I has was

```
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the DescribeCertificate operation: 1 validation error detected: Value '"arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxx:certificate/6... (truncated)' at 'certificateArn' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: arn:[\w+=/,.@-]+:acm:[\w+=/,.@-]*:[0-9]+:[\w+=,.@-]+(/[\w+=,.@-]+)*
```

it turn out the variable I save from the output has `double quote` which can't be used for the next aws cli

The **solution** are below:

1. Try to use `--query` and `--output text` when you are suing AWS CLI, it will get the value without the double quote.
2. Remove the double quote from the script

```
ARN='"arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxx:certificate/aaaaaaa-bbbbb-ccccc-dddd-fffffffffff"'

echo "${ARN//\"/}"

## Output: arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxx:certificate/aaaaaaa-bbbbb-ccccc-dddd-fffffffffff
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a space in client id in my url make sure there is no client_id="%203434..." should be client_id="3434..."